# Include images in Jekyll collection

Tags: jekyll

I have custom collections for my Jekyll project:

```yaml
collections_dir: events
collections:
  event1:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:title
    sort_by: date
  event2:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:title
    sort_by: date
```

And it's my directory structure:

```
project
├── _config.yml
└── events
    ├── _event1
    │   ├── images
    │   │   ├── title1.jpg
    │   │   └── title2.jpg
    │   ├── title1.md
    │   └── title2.md
    └── _event2
        ├── images
        │   ├── title3.jpg
        │   └── title4.jpg
        ├── title3.md
        └── title4.md
```

- I have two events collection
- Every collection has some docs
- Every doc needs an image

#### Problem

Currently, I should manually put all images in the `assets` folder so I can use them like this `/assets/img/event1/title1.jpg` :

```
project
├── _config.yml
├── events
└── assets
    └── img
        └── event1
            ├── title1.jpg
            ├── title2.jpg
            ├── ...
            └── ...
```

It's very hard to manage image assets for every collection because I have many of them. Is there any solution that every collection has its own `asset` folder ( Like the first directory tree ) and Jekyll's build process copies them in the final `_site` directory?

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Jekyll will pick **one image of every extension** from every collection, rename it to the collection's name ( `event1.jpg` / `event1.png` ) and copy that to the site's root and return an error message for other ones:

```
Conflict: The following destination is shared by multiple files.
          The written file may end up with unexpected contents.
          /<project>/_site/event1.jpg
           - /<project>/events/_event1/images/title2.jpg
           - /<project>/events/_event1/images/title3.jpg
           - /<project>/events/_event1/images/title4.jpg
```

I don't understand this behavior. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe default scopes will help you. You can set [front matter defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/front-matter-defaults/) in the _config.yml. Define a path + image or a path only per collection. You can overwrite the default in the front matter of each doc if needed.

Example:

```
collections:
  - event2

defaults:
  - scope:
      type: event2
    values:
      image: /assets/img/event2/image1.jpg
      ... or
      image_path: /assets/img/event2/
```

Now, you can access the default path or image in each doc using liquid in your links:

- full path to fixed image: `{{ page.image}}`
- path with flexible image: `{{ page.image_path}}/image1.jpg`

You could also add an array of images pointing to a different asset path and loop across images.

Example:

```
collections:
  - event2

defaults:
  - scope:
      type: event2
    values:
      images: 
        - /assets/img/event2/image1.jpg
        - /assets/img/event2/image2.jpg
        - /assets/img/event2/image3.jpg
```

Not 100% about your goal, but some code or details about your idea may help.

The roadmap for Jekyll 5 is out. The question may also be worth being asked in an issue on https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll.

Comment: Thank you, it's an interesting solution but not work as expected.

Comment: You wrote "every collection has some docs, every doc needs an image" - how do you insert the images? Default markdown or html? At work, we used a Jekyll plugin to insert images, one sub-folder for each selection, each doc has a folder named like the article. Whats not working, can you share a code sample?

Comment: You also wrote "It's very hard to manage image assets for every collection because I have many of them" - have you thought of any convention?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get your scenario running but **without using the assets folder** and **without any file copy actions**.

Version: jekyll 4.2.2

Here's a page:

You can see the relative path value for the image key in the front matter.

```
---
layout: page
title: event 2 page 1
image: "images/emmet.png"
---

event 2 page 1

![{{ page.image }}]( {{ page.image }} )
```

I have used your _config.yml:

```
collections_dir: events
collections:
  event1:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:title
    sort_by: date
  event2:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:title
    sort_by: date
```

Result and file your structure in editor tree view:

[image]

There is a nice solution for Jekyll liquid in the front matter using a plugin. This might be helpful to add a number or similar to the image in the front matter, see http://acegik.net/blog/ruby/jekyll/plugins/howto-nest-liquid-template-variables-inside-yaml-front-matter-block.html.

I think you could also use a convention for the page and image name and add a fix asset path as a collection default and then add the image tag with a leading slash to your files, maybe also using a default.